# Data Structure algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

how to Arrange the below data structures in ascending order of the time complexity required for inserts in average case scenario.
1. Sorted Array
2. Hash Table
3. Binary Search Tree
4. B+ Tree

Comment: Should be good exercise for you ... do it yourself...

Comment: sorry actually I got a question in an interview

Comment: This site is not for homework or interview questions. Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you should ponder a bit over these things.... you can easily find everything you need in google.. and ofcourse as I already mention it will be a good exercise for you... :-) .. do it yourself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer, I will give you a starters on each data structure, and let you complete the rest on your own.

1. Sorted Array: In a sorted array of size `k`, the problem with each
   insertion is you are first need to find the index `i` where the
   element should be inserted (easy), and then shift all elements
   i,i+1,...,k to the right in order to "make place" for the new
   element. This takes `O(k)` time, and it's actually `k/2` moves on average.

   So, the average complexity to insert elements to a sorted array is `1/2 + 2/2 + 3/3 + ... + n/2 = (1+...+n)/2`.

   Use [sum of arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) to see what is its complexity.
2. A hash table offers `O(1)` Average amortized case performance for inserting elements.  What happens when you do `n` operations, each `O(1)`? What will be the total coplexity?
3. In a Binary Search Tree (BST), each operation is `O(h)`, where `h` is the current height of the tree. Luckily, when adding elements at random to a binary search tree (even non self balancing) [its average height is still `O(logn)`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6342/874).

   So, to get the complexity of adding all elements, you need to sum `Some_Const*(log(1) + log(2) + ...+ log(n))`

   See hint at the end
4. Similarly to a BST, a B+ tree also takes `O(h)` time per insertion. Difference is, `h` is bounded to be logarithimic as well even in worst case. So, the calculation of time complexity is going to remain `Some_Other_Const*(log(1) + log(2) + .. + log(n))` when calculating average case.

Hints:

- `log(x) + log(y) = log(x*y)`
- `log(n!)` is in `O(nlogn)`